# Is there a universal keyboard shortcut to go to (focus) the first textbox in a web browser?

Tags: browser

I'm pretty much using my browser every day and I would like to be able to be able to go to the first textbox on any website via a keyboard shortcut. Is this possible universally without plugins? If not, is there a keyboard shortcut in Google Chrome? Also, if you have a plugin suggestion please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you use the tab key?

Comment: Tab key should work if the tabindex attribute is properly set. But it can select links and buttons too

Comment: Tab index is set by the code, so there won't be a way to do this unless you can overwrite the source. You can see tabindex in action here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_tabindex (you have to hit the tab key about 10 times before it gets to teh sample code)

Comment: 1. Press page up till you reach top of page
2. Click on the address bar
3. Press TAB button

This will take you to the first text box in the page (However the the "FIRST" text box depends on the tab index)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using Firefox, one can set in `about:config` the value of
[accessibility.tabfocus](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Accessibility.tabfocus) to `1`.
This will limit when pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> the moving of the focus to text fields only.

In Chrome you could use the extension [Input Focus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/input-focus/hdpcnibgpokgegmjefjickphdnhhniol?hl=en).
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to set focus on a page's first text field and then press the combo again to cycle through whatever other text fields are on the page.

Comment: That's very interesting, I didn't know about that. I'm wondering whether Chrome supports anything like about:config?

Answer (score 3):

The way you put it, I don't think there's any shortcut.

The only way I see is to use <kbd>Ctrl-L</kbd> to go to the address bar, and <kbd>TAB</kbd> until you get to the text box.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is just looking at this now, I made an extension that does exactly that.  The shortcut is Alt+S.

It just uses a content script and listens for the alt+s shortcut on the document body. When those keys are pressed it goes away and finds the first input text/search element and focuses on it.

You can see the code here:https://github.com/CodeRevver/Focus-First-Input

The Chrome Extension is here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/focus-on-first-input-keyb/ofngolgonfcpdanjehfjmcealkclchjg

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail on how your application works?

Comment: It just uses a content script and listens for the alt+s shortcut on the document body.  When those keys are pressed it goes away and finds the first input text/search element and focuses on it.  The code base is right there in the github repository.

Comment: You should add that information to your answer. See [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers)

Answer (score 1):

In chrome/firefox, install the [Surfingkeys](https://github.com/brookhong/Surfingkeys) extension.

Reload the webpage, and simply press "i" on your keyboard. This will focus the first textbox on the page. Works on google search page, and stackoverflow etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could a bookmarklet that if you click on it, it would jump to the first textbox on a page... creating the button you want that way...